# User Authentication in SQLLine

Tags: ignite, gridgain, sqlline

Is there any way to pass the user password manually without passing the password in the sqlline jdbc connection string (like below). We want that sqlline tool will ask to put the password to connect, how to achieve this.

./sqlline.sh --verbose=true -u "jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800;user=ignite;password=ignite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlline will always ask for user and password if they are not provided on connection string.

Comment: I tried but without username and password its failed. Can you please share the exact command to do so?

Comment: Just run `sqlline.sh` and then issue `!connect`

Comment: how to pass the driver (jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800), schema and ssl options after passing !connect
`sqlline> !connect`
`Usage: connect <url> <username> <password> [driver]`

Comment: `!connect jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800;user=ignite;password=ignite`

Comment: I don't want to put the password in the connection string and tried in this way, however it's still failing.

`sqlline> !connect jdbc:ignite:thin://node1:10800,node2:10800,node3:10800/CURATED;sslMode=require
Enter username for jdbc:ignite:thin://node1:10800,node2:10800,node:10800/CURATED;sslMode=require: igntest
Enter password for jdbc:ignite:thin://node1:10800,node2:10800,node3:10800:10800/CURATED;sslMode=require: ********
Error: Failed to connect to Ignite cluster [url=jdbc:ignite:thin://node1:10800,node2:10800,node3:10800/CURATED;sslMode=require] (state=08001,code=0)`

Comment: I'm giving correct credentials only as its running fine if I use a single command like this:
Connected to: Apache Ignite (version 2.7.6)
Driver: Apache Ignite Thin JDBC Driver (version 2.7.6)
Autocommit status: true
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
sqlline version 1.3.0
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://node1>`

Comment: Maybe sslMode is the culprit? Usually it recommends specifying key and trust stores.

Comment: As I already said everything is running fine when I run the command as a single command with username, password, ssl and I'm able to connect. As the `!connect` command suggests, what would be the value for the below:
`url`  
`driver`

Comment: Url is `jdbc:ignite:thin://host:port?key=val&key=val...`. Driver is not needed. `!connect` always works for me, for years already.